# Is Per-Monitor V2 (PMv2) awareness supported in Delphi 10.2.2?

Tags: delphi, dpi

If i check the "Enable High-DPI" checkbox for my application and at runtime call GetThreadDpiAwarenessContext() and GetAwarenessFromDpiAwarenessContext(),  PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE is returned. Microsoft calls this Per-Monitor V1 (PMv1) awareness.

According to Microsoft Per-Monitor V1 (PMv1) awareness is very limited. It is recommended that applications use PMv2.

Is PMv2 supported in Delphi 10.2.2? Will it be supported in 10.2.3.?

Comment: I've not seen any announcement that PMv2 is supported by any Delphi runtime library. I'd expect that you'd need to add any support yourself. I doubt it is difficult. You just need to write your own manifest.

Comment: Additional support for High DPI has been announced for 10.3, but the specific details about what that entails hasn't been reveiled yet.

Comment: I have created my own manifest and added this line:

<dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">permonitorv2</dpiAwareness>

but with no success, GetAwarenessFromDpiAwarenessContext() still returns PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE, instead of PROCESS_PER_MONITOR_DPI_AWARE_V2.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Works just fine here.

Comment: Well i tried it again and it's still not working.

If i remove dpiAware and add dpiAwareness in the manifest, compile the program and then extract the manifest from the program by using sigcheck, dpiAwareness is no longer present, only <dpiAware>True/PM</dpiAware>. I have no idea what i am doing wrong. I use Delphi 25.0.29039.2004 and Windows   Version 1709, OS Build 16299.248.